# What is __pyclasspath__?

Tags: jython

In situations I don't understand, when I import a module in Jython, the `__file__` has `__pyclasspath__` as a prefix:

```
>>> import coverage
>>> coverage.__file__
'__pyclasspath__/coverage/__init__$py.class'
```

and sometimes it doesn't:

```
>>> import coverage
>>> coverage.__file__
'coverage/__init__$py.class'
```

I can't reproduce the `__pyclasspath__` situation now, so the details of that path might be wrong. What does that prefix mean, and what situation causes it?

The [Jython docs](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html) mention `__pyclasspath__`, but only say it is a "special marker that we will discuss later," but then doesn't discuss it later.

Somehow this happened to me in the Jython virtualenv that tox created for me as part of the coverage.py test suite.  When I deleted the virtualenv, it was recreated, and the prefix was gone.

Answer (score 2):

If `coverage.py` is in a .jar file, and then you add the .jar file to your classpath, `coverage.__file__` will be  prefixed with `__pyclasspath__`.

Comment: There was no .jar file involved, at least not one that I created.  So it's good to know that is a situation that can occur, but is it the only way it can happen?